# MySQL import hangs on Vagrant CoreOS box on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, docker, vagrant, coreos

I have a local development setup using the following:

- Mac Yosemite 10.10.3
- Vagrant 1.7.3
- CoreOS alpha version 681.0.0
- 2 Docker containers one for apache PHP and another for mysql both based on Ubuntu 12.10

Its set up to sync the local dev directory ~/Sites to the Vagrant box using NFS, since my working directories as well as the MySQL directories are located here (~/Sites/.coreos-databases/mysql). From what I have read this is not the best type of setup but it has worked for me for quite some time as well as others at work.

Recently I have not been able to import any database dumps into this setup. The import starts and hangs approximately half way through the process. It happens on the command line as well as with Sequel Pro. It does import some of the the tables, but freezes exactly at the same spot everytime. It doesn't seem to matter what the size of the dump is - the one I have been attempting is only 104Kb. Someone else is having the same issue with a 100MB+ dump - freezing at the same spot approx halfway.

My Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

# Define the CoreOS box
config.vm.box = "coreos-alpha"
config.vm.box_url = "http://alpha.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/current/coreos_production_vagrant.json"

# Define a static IP
config.vm.network "private_network",
    ip: "33.33.33.77"

# Share the current folder via NFS
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/core/sites",
    id: "core",
    :nfs => true,
    :mount_options => ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime']

# Provision docker with shell
# config.vm.provision
config.vm.provision "shell",
    path: ".coreos-devenv/scripts/provision-docker.sh"

end
```

Dockerfile for mysql:

```
# Start with Ubuntu base
FROM ubuntu:12.10


# Install some basics
RUN apt-get update

# Install mysql
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server

# Clean up after install
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add a grants file to set up remote user
# and disbale the root user's remote access.
ADD grants.sql /etc/mysql/

# Add a conf file for correcting "listen"
ADD listen.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/

# Run mysqld on standard port
EXPOSE 3306

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/mysqld"]
CMD ["--init-file=/etc/mysql/grants.sql"]
```

I 'vagrant ssh' in and run dmesg and this is what it spits out after it freezes:

```
[  465.504357] nfs: server 33.33.33.1 not responding, still trying
[  600.091356] INFO: task mysqld:1501 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  600.092388]       Not tainted 4.0.3 #2
[  600.093277] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  600.094442] mysqld          D ffff880019dbfbc8     0  1501    939 0x00000000
[  600.095953]  ffff880019dbfbc8 ffffffff81a154c0 ffff88001ec61910 ffff880019dbfba8
[  600.098871]  ffff880019dbffd8 0000000000000000 7fffffffffffffff 0000000000000002
[  600.101594]  ffffffff8150b4e0 ffff880019dbfbe8 ffffffff8150ad57 ffff88001ed5eb18
[  600.103794] Call Trace:
[  600.104376]  [<ffffffff8150b4e0>] ? bit_wait+0x50/0x50
[  600.105934]  [<ffffffff8150ad57>] schedule+0x37/0x90
[  600.107505]  [<ffffffff8150da7c>] schedule_timeout+0x20c/0x280
[  600.108369]  [<ffffffff8101d799>] ? read_tsc+0x9/0x10
[  600.109370]  [<ffffffff810d731e>] ? ktime_get+0x3e/0xa0
[  600.110353]  [<ffffffff8101d799>] ? read_tsc+0x9/0x10
[  600.111327]  [<ffffffff810d731e>] ? ktime_get+0x3e/0xa0
[  600.112347]  [<ffffffff8150a31c>] io_schedule_timeout+0xac/0x130
[  600.113368]  [<ffffffff810a9ee7>] ? prepare_to_wait+0x57/0x90
[  600.114358]  [<ffffffff8150b516>] bit_wait_io+0x36/0x50
[  600.115332]  [<ffffffff8150b145>] __wait_on_bit+0x65/0x90
[  600.116343]  [<ffffffff81146072>] wait_on_page_bit+0xc2/0xd0
[  600.117453]  [<ffffffff810aa360>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x40/0x40
[  600.119304]  [<ffffffff81146179>] filemap_fdatawait_range+0xf9/0x190
[  600.120646]  [<ffffffff81152ffe>] ? do_writepages+0x1e/0x40
[  600.121346]  [<ffffffff81147f96>] ? __filemap_fdatawrite_range+0x56/0x70
[  600.122397]  [<ffffffff811480bf>] filemap_write_and_wait_range+0x3f/0x70
[  600.123460]  [<ffffffffa0207b1e>] nfs_file_fsync_commit+0x23e/0x3c0 [nfs]
[  600.124399]  [<ffffffff811e7bf0>] vfs_fsync_range+0x40/0xb0
[  600.126163]  [<ffffffff811e7cbd>] do_fsync+0x3d/0x70
[  600.127092]  [<ffffffff811e7f50>] SyS_fsync+0x10/0x20
[  600.128086]  [<ffffffff8150f089>] system_call_fastpath+0x12/0x17
```

Any ideas as whats going on here?

Comment: Is 33.33.33.77 really the ip address you put in there? Is that a private IP?

Comment: Yes, its setup as a private IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also using this same setup. Vagrant defaults to UDP so removing that from your setup seems to work. Haven't tested it though but I didn't run into the MYSQL issues you had.

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/core/sites",
    id: "core",
    nfs_version: "4",
    :nfs => true,
    :mount_options => ['nolock,noatime']
```

This worked for me. YMMV.

Comment: Imports working now, just a note that dropping "udp" from config.vm.synced_folder :mount_options in my config above worked for me too. I switched to this config and it works as well.